# JS работа с событием нажатия клавиш e.ShiftKey

Tags: javascript, html, css

Создать `html-страницу` со списком книг.

При щелчке на элемент, цвет текста должен меняться на оранжевый. При повторном щелчке на другую книгу, предыдущей необходимо возвращать прежний цвет.

Если при клике мышкой была зажата клавиша `Ctrl`, то элемент
***добавляется / удаляется*** из выделенных.

Если при клике мышкой была зажата клавиша `Shift`, то к выделению добавляются все элементы в промежутке от предыдущего кликнутого до текущего.

```js
function bookList(e, n) {
  var bs = document.getElementById("BookList2");
  var book = document.getElementById("list" + n);
  var li = bs.getElementsByTagName("li");

  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (book.style.backgroundColor == "orange")
      book.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    else
      book.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    return;
  }
  for (b of li) {

    b.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
  }
  book.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

  if (e.ShiftKey) {
    if (book.style.backgroundColor == "orange")
      for (b of li) {
        if (book.style.backgroundColor == "inherit")
          b.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        esle
        return;

      }
```

```html
<ol id="BookList2">
  <li onclick="bookList(event, 1)" id="list1">JavaScript: The Good Parts («JavaScript. Сильные стороны»)</li>
  <li onclick="bookList(event, 2)" id="list2">You Don’t Know JS («Вы не знаете JS»)</li>
  <li onclick="bookList(event, 3)" id="list3">Eloquent JavaScript: A Modern Introduction to Programming («Выразительный Javascript»)</li>
  <li onclick="bookList(event, 4)" id="list4">Effective JavaScript: 68 Specific Ways to Harness the Power of JavaScript («Сила JavaScript. 68 способов эффективного использования JS»)</li>
  <li onclick="bookList(event, 5)" id="list5">JavaScript: The Definitive Guide («JavaScript. Подробное руководство»)</li>
</ol>
```

Подскажите может кто то знает решение моей проблемы

Вариант с Shift  не работает, подскажите как написать проверку для  определения где произошел клик  вниз по  списку книг или вверху и как тогда если  он был вверху for-ом пройтись вверх по  списку книг

Comment: `e.shiftKey`  с маленькой

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q  спасибо, но все равно нет эффекта

Comment: Есть  ли какие то у кого то  варианты решения?!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.shiftKey)      // если нажат  shift
    { 
        if(book!=null)   //   если выбрана книга  из списка
            {
                for(var i=book ; i<pre;++i)   //  проходим циклом по  списку  от  книги  выбраной  до  предыдущей,  если она стоит в 
                                                                                списке ниже  "pre"  то идем  по списку вниз и  делаем style "orange";
                    book.style.backgroundColor="orange";  // тут пробовал писать  i.style.backgroundColor="orange";
            }
        else
            {
                for(var i=book ; i>pre;--i)
                    book.style.backgroundColor="orange";
            }
    } 
    for(b of li)
    {

    b.style.backgroundColor="inherit";


    }book.style.backgroundColor="orange";
}
Но это  не  работает, не  могу понять  где  проблема
```

Comment: var pre= book;  занес  в  переменную  прошлый элемент  нажатия

Answer (score 0):

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
rows.forEach((element) => {
  element.onmousedown = paint;
});

let lastRow;

function paint() {

  if (event.shiftKey) {
    if (lastRow.rowIndex < this.rowIndex) {
      for (let i = lastRow.rowIndex; i <= this.rowIndex; i++) {
        rows[i].classList.add('selected');
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = lastRow.rowIndex; i >= this.rowIndex; i--) {
        rows[i].classList.add('selected');
      }
    }
    return;
  }
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
      this.classList.remove('selected');
      return;
    } else {
      this.classList.add('selected');
      return;
    }
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  if (!this.classList.contains('selected')) {
    this.classList.add('selected');

  }
  if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
    lastRow = this;
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1."JavaScript for Kids: 
            A Playful Introduction to Programming" by Nick Morgan</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. "Eloquent JavaScript: 
              A Modern Introduction to Programming" by Marijn Haverbeke</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4. "Programming JavaScript Applications: 
              Robust Web Architecture with Node, HTML5, 
              and Moderns JS Libraries" by Eric Elliott</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5. "Effective JavaScript: 
              68 Specific Ways to Harness the Power of JavaScript" 
              by David Herman</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6. "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" by David Flanagan</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7. "You Don’t Know JS" by Kyle Simpson</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]